# Generating all combinations with repeating digits

Tags: c, recursion

I've been reading this site long enough to know not to hide that this is a homework assignment.  But I am trying to write a code that can generate all possible combinations of a string of only 0's and 1's.  If the length of the string is n^2, then there will be n 1's and the rest will be 0's.  The length is always a perfect square. I am coding in C and I have been trying to do it in nested loops but it seems like it could be done more easily in a recursive manner, I'm just not sure how to get that set up. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: then you should also know that you have to tag it as homework..

Comment: You should post the code that you have so far to show for your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pseudocode:

```
myfun(pos,length, ones)
  if (length==0)
     pos='\0'
     #print, collect, whatever...
     return
  if (length>ones)
    pos='0'
    myfun(pos+1,length-1, ones)
  pos='1'
  myfun(pos+1, length-1, ones-1)

task(n)
  #allocate n^2 buffer
  myfun(buffer, n*n, n)
```

Comment: In this case I assume that the buffer will be of type char*.  But then you have it recieved as "pos" which looks to be treated as an int.  Is 'pos' pointing to a specific element in the string?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this problem lends itself to recursion.  In C (and most languages), every time you call a function you create a stack frame and use a few processor cycles and a chunk of stack memory.  Any recursive solution to this problem will create n^2 stack frames, even the the recursion itself is only adding one bit of information.

A really bad solution is outlined below.  What it doesn't do:

- Exploit the fact that n is always a perfect square.
- Use memory in a very intelligent way
- Frees any of the memory it uses
- Might not even work. ;)

...but it might give you an idea of the basic pattern.

```
void foo(int zeros_left, int length_left, char *s)
{
    if (length_left == 0)
        printf("%s\n", s);
    else
    {
        if (zeros_left > 0)
        {
            char *next = malloc(strlen(s) + 2);
            strcpy(next, s);
            strcat(next, "0");
            foo(zeros_left - 1, length_left - 1, next);
        }

        if (zeros_left != length_left)
        {
            char *next = malloc(strlen(s) + 2);
            strcpy(next, s);
            strcat(next, "1");
            foo(zeros_left, length_left - 1, next);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The memory leak issue seems to be the biggest problem.  Could'nt you realloc the string instead?

Comment: Not everywhere, if you `realloc()` the string in the "zero case", then it couldn't just then be `realloc()`'d again on the "one case".

In theory you could make some use of `realloc()`, but there is a pretty obvious way to free all the `malloc()`'d memory in the solution above without impacting the correctness of the program.

Answer (score 0):

The key to modelling a problem recursively is to break a larger version of the problem into a simple calculation combined with a smaller version of the same problem, and a trivial case that terminates the recursion.

In this case, the problem is:

- For non-negative M and N, output all strings of length M that contain exactly N 1s.

You can break this down into:

- If `M = 0`, then output an empty string; otherwise
- Output all strings of length `M-1` that contain exactly `N` 1s, prefixing each with an 0; and
- If `N > 0`, then output all strings of length `M-1` that contain exactly `N-1` 1s, prefixing each with a 1.

Here, `M = 0` is the trivial case that terminates the recursion.  Turning the above into code is reasonably simple.